# How to display the correct amount of records for a chart in visual studios c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, charts

Hello all just an update, I am still facing the issues of getting the chart to display the correct number of records. I have discovered where the chart is currently getting it's numbers from however it makes no sense as to why it is using those numbers. It is from a column in the database called "mpm_code" however I have never specified for the chart to use those numbers. Here are the numbers in the database:

[image: why is my chart using these numbers?]

Here is the chart[image: chart]

And here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace RRAS
{

    public partial class formRRAS : Form
    {
        public OleDbConnection DataConnection = new OleDbConnection();

        string cmbRFR_item;

        public formRRAS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //When the form loads it sets the intial combo box RFR item to null
        private void formRRAS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.tblReject_test' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblReject_testTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);

            cmbRFR.SelectedItem = "";

            this.AcceptButton = btnSearch;

        }

        //AddRFR method, called in the NewRFRPopup
        public void AddRFR(object item)
        {
            cmbRFR.Items.Add(item);
        }

        private void change_cmbSubRFR_items()
        {
            cmbSubRFR.Items.Clear();//Clear all items in cmbSubRFR comboBox.
            switch (cmbRFR_item)//Adding your new items to cmbSubRFR.
            {
                case "":
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("");
                    cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "POSITIONING":
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Anatomy cut-off");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Rotation");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Obstructed view");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Tube or grid centering");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Motion");
                    cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "ARTEFACT":
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("ARTEFACT");
                    cmbSubRFR.Text = "ARTEFACT";
                    cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "PATIENT ID":
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Incorrect Patient");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Incorrect Study/Side");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("User Defined Error");
                    cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "EXPOSURE ERROR":
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Under Exposure");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Over Exposure");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Exposure Malfunction");
                    cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                    break;
                case "TEST IMAGES":
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Quality Control");
                    cmbSubRFR.Items.Add("Service/Test");
                    cmbSubRFR.Text = "";
                    break;
            }
        }
        private void cmbRFR_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbRFR_item != cmbRFR.SelectedItem.ToString())//This controls the changes in cmbRFR about selected item and call change_cmbSubRFR_items()
            {
                cmbRFR_item = cmbRFR.SelectedItem.ToString();
                change_cmbSubRFR_items();
            }
        }

        //The code for the button that closes the application

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //This creates the String Publisher which grabs the information from the combo box on the form.
            //Select and Dataconnection are also defined here.
            string Department = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDepartment.Text) ? "%" : txtDepartment.Text;
            string Start_Date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStart.Text) ? "%" : txtStart.Text;
            string End_Date = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEnd.Text) ? "%" : txtEnd.Text;
            string Anatomy = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAnatomy.Text) ? "%" : txtAnatomy.Text;
            string RFR = String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbRFR.Text) ? "%" : cmbRFR.Text;
            string Comment = String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbSubRFR.Text) ? "%" : cmbSubRFR.Text;

            string Select = "SELECT * FROM tblReject_test WHERE department_id LIKE '" + Department + "'" + "AND body_part_examined LIKE'" + Anatomy + "'" + "AND study_date LIKE'" + Start_Date + "'" + "AND study_date LIKE'" + End_Date + "'" + "AND reject_category LIKE'" + RFR + "'" + "AND reject_comment LIKE'" + Comment + "'";

            //DataConnection connects to the database.
            string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
            DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

            //The DataAdapter is the code that ensures both the data in the Select and DataConnection strings match.
            OleDbDataAdapter rdDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Select, DataConnection);

            try
            {
                //It then clears the datagridview and loads the data that has been selected from the DataAdapter.
                database1DataSet.tblReject_test.Clear();
                rdDataAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.tblReject_test);
            }
            catch (OleDbException exc)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }

        } //End of Search button

        //Temporary button thats loads the chart when clicked
        private void btnLoadChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.Clear();
            {
                string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
                DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

                try
                {

                    int count = database1DataSet.Tables["tblReject_test"].Rows.Count;

                    DataConnection.Open();
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = DataConnection;
                    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count, reject_category FROM tblReject_test GROUP BY reject_category";
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.AddXY(reader["reject_category"].ToString(), reader[count]);
                    }

                    DataConnection.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
                }
            }
        } //end of load chart button

        //These buttons are all from the file menu bar
        //A simple button that closes the application
        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        //This button loads the NewRFRPopup form
        private void addRFRToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewRFRPopup popup = new NewRFRPopup(this);
            popup.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void printChartToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            charRejections.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            charRejections.Printing.PrintPreview();
        }
        //End of file menu bar


        //These buttons change the format of the chart
        private void btnPie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.charRejections.Series["RFR"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
        }

        private void btnBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.charRejections.Series["RFR"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        }

        private void btnSideways_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.charRejections.Series["RFR"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar;
        }

        private void btnLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.charRejections.Series["RFR"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        }
        //end of chart formatting

    }
}
```

Comment: Break up this nested function `charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.AddXY(reader["reject_category"].ToString(), reader[count].ToString());`.    Use temporary variables to see what is actually being returned from the database and applied to the chart (nested functions are always bad).

Comment: Looks like your data are what they are but we can't really see that they are anything else but going close to "10000". Note the quotes; you have no only the x-but also the y-values added as strings. This is very dubious as the chart can't create bars of the correct proportional sizes. Try to use numbers!!!

Comment: There seems to be no connection to a DataGridView in your code. All I see is an sql and a reader! And again: Adding the y-values as strings makes __no sense at all__ Do delete the ToString() call for them! That won't change the data you see but it is one serious mistake out of the way!

Comment: Good. But I see the very same 9 values in the table also in chart, albeit in a different order. So where is the problem??

Comment: I don't want the chart to display the numbers in the post. I want the chart to display the Number of times a reject category appears and then display it on the chart so when I press a button, the chart will display how many positionings there are, how many artefacts, etc.

Comment: so you should either use linq or sql to select a count and do a group by rejCat, maybe like this: Select count(*), yourCategory from yourTable group by yourCategory

Comment: Hello TaW, sorry if I am being a complete noob at this but how would you go about writing the SQL statement as the one you stated above didn't work.

Comment: 'didn't work' is not a helpful description! If you replace the sql select in your code by this: `SELECT COUNT(*) as count,reject_category  FROM tblReject_test  GROUP BY reject_category` does it run?

Comment: Using that code I get this [error](http://i.snag.gy/DJ17z.jpg)

Revised version of code is in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue has been sorted thanks to a friend of mine. This relates to the code that TaW posted the other day. Thanks for everyone's time and suggestions. The fixed code is below:

```
private void btnLoadChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.Clear();
        {
            string connectiontring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdb";
            DataConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectiontring);

            try
            {

                DataConnection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = DataConnection;
                string query = "SELECT COUNT(reject_category) as reject, reject_category FROM tblReject_test GROUP BY reject_category";
                command.CommandText = query;


                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    charRejections.Series["RFR"].Points.AddXY(reader["reject_category"].ToString(), reader["reject"].ToString());
                }

                DataConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
        } 
    }//end of load chart button
```